# Using power results in ValueError: a <= 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have written the following code but it fails with a `ValueError`.

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

t = arange(-10, 10, 20/(1001-1))
x = 1./sqrt(2*pi)*exp(power(-(t*t), 2))
```

Specifically, the error message I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: a <= 0
    x = 1./sqrt(2*pi)*exp(power(-(t*t), 2))
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 3214, in mtrand.RandomState.power (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:24592)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3Qt5\notebooks\untitled1.py", line 6, in <module>
```

Any idea what the issue might be here?

Comment: Stop using `import *`, especially `from pylab import *`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I upvoted @user2357112's comment, but that isn't a strong enough agreement in this case.  Really, truly, emphatically: don't use `import *`!  It is the source of the problem in this case.  Both `numpy` and `pylab` define a function called `power`, but they are completely different.  Because you imported `pylab` after `numpy` using `import *`, the `pylab` version is the one you end up with.  What is `pylab.power`?  From the docstring:  *"power(a, size=None)   
Draws samples in [0, 1] from a power distribution with positive
exponent a - 1."*

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser unless you're aware of a dup, why not add it as an answer?

Comment: While not exactly a dup, perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad is "morally" a dup, and there are probably other questions where the fundamental problem is a namespace clash resulting from `import *`, but those are hard to search for, so sure, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both `numpy` and `pylab` define a function called `power`, but they are completely different. Because you imported `pylab` after `numpy` using `import *`, the `pylab` version is the one you end up with. What is `pylab.power`? From the docstring:

```
power(a, size=None)

Draws samples in [0, 1] from a power distribution with positive exponent a - 1.
```

The moral of the story: **don't use `import *`**.  In this case, it is common to use `import numpy as np`:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(-10, 10, 20/(1001-1))
x = 1./np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*np.exp(np.power(-(t*t), 2))
```

Further reading:

- [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
- [Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html) (That's in the Python 2 documentation, but it also applies to Python 3.)